# Deployment template validation failed while deploying machine in azure

Tags: azure, vagrant, azure-networking

Facing following issues while performing vagrant up with azure provider

```
"response": {
    "body": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"InvalidTemplate\",\"message\":\"Deployment template validation failed: 'The value fo
r the template parameter 'adminPassword' at line '1' and column '306' is not provided. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-dep
loy/#parameter-file for usage details.'.\"}}",
```

**Template file:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vaults_VaultVagrant_name": {
      "defaultValue": "VaultVagrant",
      "type": "String"
    },
    "AdminPassword":{
    "type":"securestring"
    }

  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
      "name": "[parameters('vaults_VaultVagrant_name')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-01",
      "location": "eastus",
      "tags": {},
      "properties": {
        "sku": {
          "family": "A",
          "name": "standard"
        },
        "tenantId": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
        "accessPolicies": [
          {
            "tenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "objectId": "1efb1891-8ad4-4f69-9e0d-f5849e6f8c98",
            "permissions": {
              "keys": [
                "get",
                "create",
                "delete",
                "list",
                "update",
                "import",
                "backup",
                "restore"
              ],
              "secrets": [
                "all"
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "enabledForDeployment": true
      },
      "resources": [],
      "dependsOn": []
    }

  ]
}
```

**Parameter**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "AdminPassword": {
            "reference": {
               "keyVault": {
                  "id":"/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/azurevag/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/VaultVagrant"
               }, 
               "secretName": "vagrant" 
            }   
        }
   }
}
```

I am deploying both files from local machine as like in below

> azure group deployment create -f "c:\MyTemplates\example.json" -e
>   "c:\MyTemplates\example.params.json" -g examplegroup -n
>   exampledeployment

**ISSUE**:after deployment is successfully created checked the deployment script in azure portal where both the files look like below

**TemplateFile**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vaults_VaultVagrant_name": {
      "defaultValue": "VaultVagrant",
      "type": "String"
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/azurevag/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/VaultVagrant'.",
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
      "name": "[parameters('vaults_VaultVagrant_name')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-01",
      "location": "eastus",
      "tags": {},
      "properties": {
        "sku": {
          "family": "A",
          "name": "standard"
        },
        "tenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "accessPolicies": [
          {
            "tenantId": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
            "objectId": "1efb1891-8ad4-4f69-9e0d-f5849e6f8c98",
            "permissions": {
              "keys": [
                "get",
                "create",
                "delete",
                "list",
                "update",
                "import",
                "backup",
                "restore"
              ],
              "secrets": [
                "all"
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "enabledForDeployment": true
      },
      "resources": [],
      "dependsOn": []
    }
  ]
}
```

**Note:**Parameter adminpassword is missing after deployment

**Parameter file:**

parameter file is empty.
How the values(admin password) are missed after deployment?

Comment: if possible, maybe you could share your template.

Comment: `"AdminPassword": {
            "reference": {
               "keyVault": {
                  "id":"/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/azurevag/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/VaultVagrant"
               }, ` is your AdminPassword?

Comment: @Walter-MSFT Yes.I have passed the secret value through key vault

Comment: @JeevaS I'm a bit confused by your templates, by the looks of it your ARM template is creating a keyvault, but your paramater file is looking up a password from the same keyvault, this can't work as teh Keyvault doesn't exist at the time the param file is run, unless you have two keyvaults?

Comment: @Walter-MSFT Key vault is created manually and then secure key is set
Valutname:VaultVagrant. 
couldn't find the mistake what i have done 
Could you suggest me the work around to fix this?

Comment: @JeevaS Do you try to get the keyvault  and give the value to AdminPassword?

Comment: @Walter-MSFT yes. I have used key vault to pass the admin password in secure way..but i couldn't even pass the value now.

Answer (score 0):

The ARM template is expecting  a parameter called AdminPassword which it's not received. Without seeing your template and parameters it's difficult to know why, but most templates expect parameters as a secure string, so make sure you are providing it in the right format.

Comment: i have added both template files

Answer (score 0):

According to your error, maybe your template lost the parameter ‘adminPassword’ or had some grammar error in column ‘306’. Maybe you could check your template. I suggest you use tools to check your template. [JSON Formatter and Validator](https://www.site24x7.com/tools/json-formatter.html) maybe a good option.

[image]

Comment: Validated the templates and I have added the template files. there  is no grammatical error or syntax error in template files.kindly check the template and let me know if any issues?

Comment: @JeevaS Yes,there is no grammatical error or syntax error. Do you try to deploy it by other ways? Maybe you could ask the question on Azure support forms.

Comment: @JeevaS Maybe you could try to this link to deploy vagrant https://github.com/Azure/vagrant-azure